# Filter list items based on the selection from another list in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice

I'm of zero experience with LibreOffice Writer advanced features and I am currently creating a form with two lists. The main list has six list items, while the other list has two sub-items specific to the selection from the first main list. I need to make these to list work in a way that when I select one item from the main list only the two specific sub-list items appear on the second list automatically. How can I do that?
Image attached for illustration:
[image]

Comment: It seems to me that you have chosen a not very reliable method of filling out the form. Indeed, what happens if the user selects a value in the first list, gets a limited selection of values in the second list, selects a value in the second list (is that what you're describing?). Now the user will select another value in the first list and stop there, leaving the wrong value in the second field. Do you think the user won't do this? I have to disappoint you - someday someone will definitely do this.